# Triangular image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, geometry

I've searched everywhere for many weeks but I can't find an answer for my problem.

Is it possible to have an image inside a regular triangle?

I've seen many ways to create a shape or a mask, but I need a real triangle because I need to have several triangles next to each other, with some of them aligned upside-dwn, like in this= image:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=d49c960

I've used color to divide the two types of triangle, but all of them have images instead colors.

I've tried using skewX, skewY and rotate, I have a sufficient result but it's not perfect:

```
<div class='pageTri2'>
<a href='#' class='option2'>
    <img src='image.jpg'>
</a>
</div>

<style>
.pageTri2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 250px; height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.option2, .option2 img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.option2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(-25deg) skewY(45deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
.option2:first-child {
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.option2:last-child {
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.option2 img { opacity: .75; transition: .5s; }
.option2 img:hover { opacity: 1; }
.option2 img, .option2:after {
transform: skewX(-20deg) skewY(-20deg) rotate(-50deg);
transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
}
.option2:first-child:after { top: 0; left: 0; }
.option2:last-child:after { right: 0; bottom: 0; }
</style>
```

Is it possible to have a perfect result?
Or maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction?

Thanks
Ale

EDIT: I've done it!! Thanks to @Spudley for address me to SVG and thanks to @o.v. for the suggestion to use jsfiddle.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wkJKA/

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve (I see no images in your example), but you can probably accomplish this with transparent PNG images and negative margins.

Comment: I can't use transparent png I need to use rect images inside the triangles. In my example there is a link to the final result. In each triangle need to be inserted a triangle, like the triangle is a mask of a normal image. Is it more clear?

Comment: Something like that is more clear? http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=55f6d9b

Answer (score 6):

In all seriousness, having seen your mock-up image of what you're trying to achieve, I'd say drop the idea of doing it in CSS.

Stuff like this is much better done using SVG rather than CSS. CSS simply wasn't designed for creating complex shape patterns. It can do it, but it gets messy quickly, and for something like the effect you're after, you'll end up needing some extra HTML markup. SVG is designed for exactly this kind of thing, and does it well.

The only downside is lack of support for SVG in old IE versions, but there are work-arounds for this. (and in any case, old-IE support clearly isn't a priority for you, given that you're already using `transform` and other CSS that doesn't work with old IE)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've never used SVG, but you think is possible to transform a PNG/JPG in a triangular version in SVG? I'll search some information.

Comment: SVG is vector graphics - ie made of lines and shapes; PNG/JPG are bitmaps - ie made of pixels. They work differently, so converting may not produce perfect results, but it may be a good place to start. A tool such as Inkscape (which is free) might help here. But simple triangles as per your example shouldn't need much work to create from scratch.

Comment: OK but you are saying to convert the image to svg before upload it online, if I've understood well. I need something that do this programmatically. Like upload a JPG/PNG and create a triangular thumbnail.
I've tried many possibility to create the triangle with my background with the code that I've wrote, but I can't have it perfect. So it's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

use transparent png or simply do triangles with css. Here is a link to css shapes http://www.css3shapes.com

Comment: OK, but it's not what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on specifics of border rendering to achieve a triangle-looking shape. The shape could then be added with pseudoelements.

```
.pointy:before {
  border:50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:86px solid green;
  border-top:0px solid transparent;/*renders looking like a triangle with 100px sides*/
  width:0;
  height:0;
  display:inline-block;
  content:"";
  margin:0 -75px -5px 0; /*for a 50x50 icon*/
}
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/gvPLh/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm trying to have the triangle as a mask of the image and than put triangles one near each other like the image I've attached to the first post.

Comment: @stinkokenzo: oh, I see, I must have missed the point reading the question first time around :) For future reference I suggest you add your code to something like jsfiddle.net - not only it's a good sandbox to rapidly mock things up in, it also gives a quick preview of what you've done so far to other stackoverflowers